# When typing in Open Resource dialog, is there a way to find files by directory instead of just the file name?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have been using extensively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + to find and open files in my Eclipse project. But sometimes I know the directory where my files are (or part of it) but I don't know exactly their names.

When doing search, it seems it only takes into consideration the name of the files, and not their paths. I'd like to be able to refine the search by path.

For instance, if I have a folder X with 3 files in it, I'd like that typing X would bring up the 3 files, so I could choose them. Or that it'd actually let me select the X folder itself!

Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the 'Open Resource' dialog
- Type `*X/` to list all files in the folder `X`. Ex search: `*myDir/myFile`.
  *Important: the preceding asterisk (`*`) is required to make the search apply to folders and paths too.*

Answer (score 2):

Here are the implementation notes: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86973