# Search for Folder Name Using Eclipse "Search in File"

Tags: eclipse

How can I use 'search in path' for Eclipse Mars 2.0 to find a string pattern in either the name of a file and **also find a string pattern in the name of a folder?**

I have a folder named 'Personal Finance' in a git repo that I primarily use Eclipse to work with. When I search in file for 'Finance' the only search results that show up are in files themselves. Is there a way in Eclipse to search file names and folder names simultaneously?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not use Search dialog(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) for this. It searches inside the file content.

Use open resource dialog(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
In the input pattern text box enter

> <Folder/File NamePatter>**/**

For example:

1. `*handler/`

   This will list all files which has `handler` string in their names **and** present under the folders which has `handler` string in their names.
2. `*handler/*nature`

   This will list all files which has `nature` string in their names **and** present under the folders which has `handler` string in their names.

See this post for more details [When typing in Open Resource dialog, is there a way to find files by directory instead of just the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752342/when-typing-in-open-resource-dialog-is-there-a-way-to-find-files-by-directory-i) also look into this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86973) and read all comments.

---

This may not interest to you but have a look on it:

In this [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/07/31/eclipse-papercut-9-filtered-packageexplorer-by-project-name/) you can find the details of a plugin which filters resource in package explorer view by name patterns. But now its limited to filter only ***projects***. Go through [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386309) and [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149110)

Comment: Works! Basically it is expecting a regular expression to match the path the user is searching for.

Comment: On a Mac, it's command-shift-R