# Eclipse: Open ressource on folder

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is it possible in Eclipse (pydev) to include folder (names) in the *Open Ressource* file navigation?

---

When opening specific files in one of my projects I often use the *Open Ressource* (see the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-46ag.htm)) dialog (Navigate -> Open Ressource). This way I don't have to remember (or keep track in a multi-developer project), where a specific file is placed, but only the file name.

This  only seems to filter through file names. I would rather like to

- (optionally) include the folder name
- open python package file `__init__.py` in the editor
  (or any other configurable custom file like `__custom_module__.py`)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39568618/1391924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding any file, `Ctrl+Shift+R` (open resource) is good, but to find a Python package/module/class/method, `Ctrl+Shift+T` (Python tokens browser) is better -- you can filter by the module name as you want -- see the docs on the dialog when you open the tokens browser.

**Note:** you need to focus some PyDev editor for it to become active (such as the PyDev package explorer or a PyDev editor).

**Note 2:** You may still use a filter with folders in the open resource if you filter with the path (i.e.: `*package/file*.py`)