# how to find file (Open Type) by project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse (neon) I have several projects with similar files
I want to able to pick project when open type maybe using Path or Project name
Is there any plugin or similar way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for open resource(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) not open type(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

IMHO there  is no way to filter out **types** by their paths, as because same type(ex Enum/Inner class) may exist in different Java classes.

Yes. You can filter out resources by project/folder path. Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39568618/1391924

Answer (score 0):

Open Resource and Open Type both let You use *Working Sets*.

So You can define a WS per project or whatever makes sense for You and use the one You need at the given moment.

You can choose the WS directly in the modal dialog.